# Mybatis Many-to-Many best practice

Tags: java, mybatis

Member table:

```
id int  
name varchar
```

Club table:

```
id int  
name varchar
```

Member and Club index table:

```
member_id int  
club_id int  
register_date timestamp
```

If I want to query a member by `id` with clubs and the register time of each club, how should I design the POJO. Should I map the index table to an entity which contains the references of member and club? Or there is better practice?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an object model I recommend:

```java
class Member {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    List<ClubRegistration> clubRegistrations;
}

class Club {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    List<MemberRegistration> memberRegistrations;
}

class ClubRegistration {
    Club club;
    Date date;
}

class MemberRegistration {
    Member member;
    Date date;
}
```

So that you can get data in both ways: member with its clubs or club with its members.

The SQL query:

```sql
SELECT m.id AS memberId, m.name AS memberName, c.id AS clubId, c.name AS clubName, register_Date
FROM member m
         INNER JOIN member_club mc ON m.id = mc.member_id
         INNER JOIN club c ON mc.club_id = c.id
WHERE {what you want}
```

ResultMap for the case you ask:

```xml
<resultMap id="memberRM" type="Member">
  <id column="memberId" property="id"/>
  <result column="memberName" property="name"/>
  <collection property="clubRegistrations" ofType="ClubRegistration">
    <result column="register_Date" property="date" />
    <association property="club" javaType="Club">
      <id column="clubId" property="id"/>
      <result column="clubName" property="name"/>
    </association>
  </collection>
</resultMap>
```

Just swap Member/Club for the other case.

You should then even reference resultMap instead of nest define:

```
<association property="club" resultMap="clubRM" />
```

Although I've not checked it myself, [the circular reference issue that would arise is managed bay MyBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667427/7076047).

Comment: just updated answer to go further. let me know if it works well.